# WCF : due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf

I'm getting this exception:

> The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IUserService/HelloWorld' cannot be >  > processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Web.Config is as follows

**Server**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="API.UserService">
        <endpoint 
          name ="basic"
          address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration ="basicBinding"
          contract="API.IUserService" />
        <endpoint 
          address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicBinding" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"  
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"></security>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client**

```
        <client>
          <endpoint
            name ="basic"
            address="http://localhost:8080/UserService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration ="basicBinding"
            contract="API.IUserService" />
        </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Do you have a `basicBinding` binding section in your client config file?

Comment: Also, can you post an example of how you are calling the service in your code?